# npm run dev command is in same status when try to run a nextjs application

Tags: next.js

I have created a `Next Js` application by using `npx create-next-app`
When I try to run the application using `npm run dev`. It is always in ready status (Please see the attched image). [Nothing happens after that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuAXL.png)

**I tried several times after restarting system but no use.**

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't indicate a problem in my experience. If you're developing on your local machine, visit http://localhost:3000 for nextjs to compile and serve your webpage. Feedback on the console should appear thereafter.

Hope this helps!